# When typing, mouse pointer stops moving

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have done a typical installation of Ubuntu 12.04 precise,
but i seem to have a small issue.
When i type anything in the keyboard or when i'm playing a game that requires two hands
(e.g. Nexuiz) the mouse doesn't respond.
So, for example in Nexuiz, when i am moving i can't turn around at all.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a way, this is a known bug, but not fixed yet. Basically this is caused by the mouseemu. You just have to kill it or to remove it. Here is the launchpad page :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mouseemu/+bug/113344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remove the **mouseemu** and it works. Mouseemu just work with 2.6 kernel. Remove it from synaptic or ubuntu software center. This is not a kernel's fault.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have "Disable touchpad while typing" checked in the "Mouse & Touchpad" system settings area.
Have you checked this?

Comment: Hi in the Mouse and Touchpad system settings area, it has only one tab Mouse

Comment: Out of curiosity, what mouse & keyboard are you using?
Are they plugged in the same USB host?

Comment: Keyboard: Some old Logitech on the green hub (not the USB one)
Mouse : Common Microsoft on Usb